# Jenkins add/update to all jobs : should have email alerts to default recipients list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, email-ext

our jenkins have about 100 jobs already, i want to add editable email notification for all jobs, so that all jobs should have email alerts to default recipients list.   Looking for Groovy Script for Jenkins Script Console to Add or Modify email notification  Setting .

```
Jenkins.instance.items.each { item ->

  println("JOB: " + item.name)

  // code for setting email notification if not exist
  if(item.XXXX == null) {
    println("No email notification step ")

  } 
   else {
    //   code to update the current email settings 
    println("Set new setting")

  }
 item.save()
 println(" done")

}
```

Or some other automated way is also fine. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher` and all jobs already have the step added, this should probably cover the iteration part.

```
// Gets all jobs and folders recursively
items = Jenkins.instance.getAllItems();

items.each { item ->
   def status = ''
   def base_email = ''
   def ext_email = []
   if (item.class.name == "hudson.model.FreeStyleProject") {
      item.publishersList.findAll {it instanceof hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher}.each { publisher ->
         status = publisher.disabled 
         base_email=publisher.recipientList?.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", " ")
         publisher.configuredTriggers?.each { entry ->
            if (entry.email.recipientList) {
                ext_email << "${entry.class.name.replace("hudson.plugins.emailext.plugins.trigger.", "")}: ${entry.email.recipientList?.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", " ")}"
            }
         }
      }
      if ( base_email ) {
            println item.fullName + "( " + status + " )"
            println "  +- " + base_email
            ext_email.each {             
               println "   - " + it
            }
      } else {
         println "# " + item.fullName
      }
   }
}
return
```

If you are using `hudson.tasks.Mailer`,it's only one field: `publisher.recipients`

Then you either

```
publisher.recipientList="someone@somewhere.com"
item.save()
```

or equivalent as needed.

Note: Extended Email plugin has a toggle to disable sending emails "Disable Extended Email Publisher (`publisher.disabled`), so report on that too.

If you need to add the plugin, then it would be something like:
`item.publishersList.add(new hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher(<parameters>)`([see javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/email-ext/hudson/plugins/emailext/ExtendedEmailPublisher.html))

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response.  when i tried i got the error.. org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 29: unexpected char: 0xFFFF @ line 29, column 9.
   return 0

Comment: Assume that i don't have editable email notification step enable for all the jobs.   How can i enable it for all jobs, with groovy script. i think this is fine for now . can you help ?

Comment: I have re-pasted the code; maybe have been a bad character at end (zero not req'd). Added a reference to the javadoc.

Comment: i added this part  in your else part , to add the email step to the missing jobs.  else {
          println "# " + item.fullName  
  //item.publishersList.remove(hudson.plugins.emailext.ExtendedEmailPublisher)
 def eep = new ExtendedEmailPublisher();
    eep.recipientList = "\$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS"
    eep.defaultSubject = "\$DEFAULT_SUBJECT"
    eep.defaultContent = "\$DEFAULT_CONTENT"
    // With some triggers                     }            for some reason , adding  triggers didn't work  for me ...

Comment: this didn't work for me  , this is optimal solution for me.                                                                                               
       // With some triggers                                                 
       eep.configuredTriggers.add(new FailureTrigger(
      email : new EmailType(
        sendToRecipientList : true,
        body : ExtendedEmailPublisher.PROJECT_DEFAULT_BODY_TEXT,
        subject : ExtendedEmailPublisher.PROJECT_DEFAULT_SUBJECT_TEXT )))